# Clisp compile error: "string" is not a real number

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to lisp, so apologies if this question sounds pedantic:

I'm trying to build a Lisp program for a homework project that changes a series of Roman numbers into decimal numbers, using 1 function and just recursion. No variables, progn, assignments, or loops are allowed.

What I have so far is this:

```
(defun tonormal (inputs &optional (state 1) rostr)
(COND
    ((= state 1) (dolist (x inputs) (print (toroman nil 2 x))))
    ((= state 2) (COND
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 1) "M" )  (+ 1000 (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 1))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 2) "CM")  (+ 900  (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 2))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 1) "D" )  (+ 500  (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 1))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 2) "CD")  (+ 400  (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 2))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 1) "C" )  (+ 100  (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 1))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 2) "XC")  (+ 90   (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 2))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 1) "L" )  (+ 50   (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 1))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 2) "XL")  (+ 40   (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 2))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 1) "X" )  (+ 10   (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 1))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 2) "IX")  (+ 9    (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 2))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 1) "V" )  (+ 5    (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 1))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 2) "IV")  (+ 4    (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 2))))
                ((equal (subseq rostr 0 1) "I" )  (+ 1    (toroman nil 2 (subseq rostr 1))))
                ((= (length rostr) 0) (values))))))
```

When I try to call the function, I get this error message:

```
[191]> (tonormal '("MXXIV" "MMCMXX"))

*** - >=: "MXXIV" is not a real number
```

Is there any reason this damnable little error is popping up? If anyone could help, it'd be greatly appreciated. I've been working at it for hours.

Comment: `(length length rostr)` - what does this expression mean?

Comment: Who knows what `toroman` is doing...

Comment: @Rainer -er, that's a typo. Thank you for pointing it out. It's meant to check when the length of the passed string is zero. Suprisingly, toroman works fine.

Comment: @Hex37 Btw, format can format numbers as Roman Numerals. (format t "~@R" <number>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the state variable is supposed to be doing, but it's optional with a default value of 1, and since you're not passing a different value into (tonormal '("MXXIV" "MMCMXX")), it's triggering the first cond clause, meaning it's passing "MXXIV" into (toroman ...), which probably expects a numeric input.

Comment: Ahhh you just answered my own question. I didn't mean to have it go to "toroman". Thank you!